# Disable overscrolling / bounce effect in Blackberry Phonegap app?

Tags: cordova, jquery-mobile, blackberry

I just started testing a Blackberry app made with phonegap and noticed that the app overscrolls / has a bouncing effect when you scroll to the top or bottom. Is there a way to disable this from happening? It looks like you can use  to prevent this from happening in iOS phonegap apps, is there an equivalent option for Blackberry apps?